# Hyper-sensitive "v" key on my laptop keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard

When the "v" key on my laptop is barely touched, it behaves as if it was pressed. It is the only key on the keyboard that behaves this way. All other keys only register a keystroke when the key is fully depressed.

What should I do to troubleshoot and fix the issue?

The laptop is a Lenovo T410, in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for things lodged under the V key.

But you will probably be better off [replacing the keyboard](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-74569).

Answer (score 0):

I have an external thinkpad keyboard that is identical to the built-in keyboard on my T460. The <kbd>E</kbd> key started having this problem.

I took it off as carefully as I could, but still one of the four hinges broke under the key (the top right). I watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwPq2NiBeq0) to see the mechanism and design first.

With one corner missing, the key can still work fine. However, I think the ideal way to remove it (and the method I used after that top corner broke off) would be to use two very small flathead screwdrivers to stretch the sidewall of the black piece out so that the post that goes through the sidewall connecting the black and white pieces can slip out. Once this is done, the mechanism removes easily.

Then there is a glued down rubber piece looking at you. (Unlike in the video, my rubber piece was non-removable.) I didn't have any compressed air available, so I just scraped around underneath this rubber piece.

My key is at least now functional, and is much improved, but I'm still getting sporadic 'e' strikes popping up randomly. A second ago, however, it was completely dysfunctional. I will probably remove it again and use some paper towel wetted with alcohol and shoved around underneath with the screwdriver to try thoroughly cleaning the contact point under the rubber.